Qiskit AttributeError: 'SamplerPubResult' object has no attribute 'get_statevector'
I use qiskit 1.2.2m and get this error
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-93563cbef15a> in <cell line: 90>()
     88 
     89 # Compute quantum kernel
---> 90 quantum_kernel_train = compute_quantum_kernel(X_train, X_train, feature_map, backend, batch_size)
     91 quantum_kernel_test = compute_quantum_kernel(X_test, X_train, feature_map, backend, batch_size)
     92 

<ipython-input-33-93563cbef15a> in compute_quantum_kernel(X1, X2, feature_map, backend, batch_size)
     73             for k, circuit in enumerate(qc_list):
     74                 circuit_result = job.result()[k]  # Access result for each circuit
---> 75                 statevector = circuit_result.get_statevector(circuit)  # Get statevector from circuit
     76                 statevector1 = np.abs(statevector) ** 2
     77                 qc2 = QuantumCircuit(feature_map.num_qubits)

AttributeError: 'SamplerPubResult' object has no attribute 'get_statevector'

Here is my code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from qiskit_aer import Aer  # Import Aer for simulator backend
from qiskit.primitives import StatevectorSampler  # Import StatevectorSampler from qiskit.primitives
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZZFeatureMap
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load data
data = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/x.csv")

# Convert 'timestamp' to datetime format
data["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(data["timestamp"])
data.set_index("timestamp", inplace=True)

# Select relevant features and target variable
features = ["open", "high", "low", "close", "volume"]
target = "close"
X = data[features]
y = data[target]

# Convert target to binary classification
y_binary = (y.shift(-1) > y).astype(int).dropna()
X = X.iloc[:-1]  # Align X with y_binary

# Normalize features
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
y_binary = y_binary.iloc[:-1]  # Ensure alignment

# Train/test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, y_binary, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)

X_train = X_train[:50]  # Limit to 50 samples for training
y_train = y_train[:50]
X_test = X_test[:20]    # Limit to 20 samples for testing
y_test = y_test[:20]

# Define feature map for quantum kernel
feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(feature_dimension=X_train.shape[1], reps=2, entanglement="full")

# Quantum backend (simulator)
backend = Aer.get_backend("aer_simulator")
batch_size = 100  # Adjust batch size

def compute_quantum_kernel(X1, X2, feature_map, backend, batch_size):
    """Compute quantum kernel using statevector similarity."""
    num_samples1 = X1.shape[0]
    num_samples2 = X2.shape[0]
    kernel_matrix = np.zeros((num_samples1, num_samples2))
    sampler = StatevectorSampler()  # Updated sampler class for Qiskit 1.2.2

    for i in range(0, num_samples1, batch_size):
        end_i = min(i + batch_size, num_samples1)
        for j in range(num_samples2):
            qc_list = []
            for k in range(i, end_i):
                qc = QuantumCircuit(feature_map.num_qubits)
                qc.append(feature_map, range(feature_map.num_qubits))
                qc = qc.assign_parameters(X1[k])
                # Add measurement instructions
                qc.measure_all()  # Measure all qubits
                qc_list.append(qc)
            transpiled_qc_list = transpile(qc_list, backend)
            job = sampler.run(transpiled_qc_list)

            for k, circuit in enumerate(qc_list):
                statevector = sampler.get_statevector(circuit)  # Get statevector for each circuit
                statevector1 = np.abs(statevector.data) ** 2
                qc2 = QuantumCircuit(feature_map.num_qubits)
                qc2.append(feature_map, range(feature_map.num_qubits))
                qc2 = qc2.assign_parameters(X2[j])
                qc2.measure_all()  # Measure all qubits
                transpiled_qc2 = transpile(qc2, backend)
                job2 = sampler.run([transpiled_qc2])
                result2 = job2.result()
                statevector2 = np.abs(result2.statevectors[0].data) ** 2
                kernel_matrix[i + k, j] = np.abs(np.dot(statevector1, statevector2)) ** 2

    return kernel_matrix

# Compute quantum kernel
quantum_kernel_train = compute_quantum_kernel(X_train, X_train, feature_map, backend, batch_size)
quantum_kernel_test = compute_quantum_kernel(X_test, X_train, feature_map, backend, batch_size)

# Train SVM with quantum kernel
svm = SVC(kernel='precomputed')
svm.fit(quantum_kernel_train, y_train)

# Save model
joblib.dump(svm, 'svm_model.joblib')

# Predict and evaluate
y_pred = svm.predict(quantum_kernel_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(f"Model accuracy: {accuracy:.2f}")

# Plot results
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(y_test.reset_index(drop=True), label='True Prices', color='blue')
plt.plot(y_pred, label='Predicted Prices', color='orange')
plt.title('True vs Predicted Prices')
plt.xlabel('Sample Index')
plt.ylabel('Price Direction')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()


SamplerPubResult have no method called get_statevector...
